# How do I beat the last 2 test your might in Mortal Kombat?

Tags: mortal-kombat-9

I've been beating the test your might from the challenge tower with no problems up till the last two.  The technique I used is to tap all 4 buttons with my thumb and first 3 fingers.  Once the meter overshoots the mark, I hit the bumper button.

This technique is not working so well on the last 2 challenges.  Are there any hints on how to beat them?  I'm playing on the PS3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to put the controller upside down on my coffee table, and use three fingers and a thumb and mash as quick as I could.  Then used my knee to hit the trigger.

Yes, I'm serious...

Far easier is if you have a fight stick.  You can happy hit all the buttons you need at once.  I bought a fight stick for MK and the TYM challenges are a breeze.

Answer (score 1):

I wait until the counter is at 4 or 5 (so I don't get sweaty) and vibrate my thumb (not too fast, otherwise it won't register) for 3 seconds. I try to get near the ring, and I speed up at the last second; the clock strikes for you and Bob's your uncle!

Answer (score 0):

I hold my controller almost sideways with my right hand on the right side (I'm right handed) and grip my left hand over the right bumper and trigger and spam a,b,y or x with both thumbs  until its over the line then I press the right trigger (I did beat the last level using this method).

Answer (score 0):

USING A PEN WORKS EXCEPT I had my husband hit L2 while I held the other side of my controller and slid the pen back and forth. That last one was killer. I apparently can't do both while watching the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Hold the controller normally, Right Index middle and thumb in a triangle on the buttons left index on the left trigger, move your right finger shape in a circle on the buttons really fast, as soon as it goes in the ring then press the trigger.
(I got blisters lol) please use some sort of glove.

Answer (score -1):

I used my index and middle fingers (two buttons each finger) to tap as quickly as posible, make sure you make it to the mark quickly, or else you'll start to get tired.

Answer (score -1):

I got a spatula and just rubbed it so all of the buttons were being pressed really fast.